# OpenOffice Mail Merger - 530 Authenthication Required

Tags: email, openoffice

In OpenOffice Writer, I'm trying to to do a mail merge with OpenOffice Base. When I test the email settings, OpenOffice claims they work. However, when I try to do the actual mail merge, OpenOffice displays an error stating "Emails could not be sent", with the error being a 530 authentication required. Enabling or disabling SSL makes no difference, the same error still occurs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What debug logs have you collected? And how are you testing the email? I ask about the testing because it's happened to me. I had to dig through nitty gritty settings to figure out what happened and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know to what kind of an email server you are trying to connect
(for example gmail), your email client and the exact error message that you are getting.

If the problem is that OpenOffice is trying to send via unencrypted SMTP,
while your email server (for example gmail) requires SSL or TLS,
you need to update OpenOffice's settings to use the SSL or TLS on one of the ports
accepted by your email server.

In OpenOffice:

1. Tools -> Options
2. OpenOffice.org Writer -> Mail Merge E-mail
3. Set port 465, and select `Use Secure Connection (SSL)`
4. Click `Server authentication` to set your username and password.